# TypeError: mul_(): argument 'other' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm running the code with https://github.com/safe-graph/GNN-FakeNews.When training the model, I successfully loaded the dataset after running the first line of code below.

```
dataset = FNNDataset(root='/home/ai/data/szl/GNN-FakeNews-main/data', feature='bert', empty=False, name='politifact', transform=ToUndirected())

args.num_classes = dataset.num_classes
args.num_features = dataset.num_features
```

But the second line of code gives an error.The error is as follows：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shaozhulin/.pycharm_helpers/profiler/run_profiler.py", line 173, in <module>
    profiler.run(file)
  File "/home/shaozhulin/.pycharm_helpers/profiler/run_profiler.py", line 89, in run
    execfile(file, globals, globals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/shaozhulin/.pycharm_helpers/profiler/prof_util.py", line 30, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/ai/data/szl/GNN-FakeNews-main/gnn_model/gnn.py", line 123, in <module>
    args.num_classes = int(dataset.num_classes)
  File "/home/shaozhulin/.conda/envs/szlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/in_memory_dataset.py", line 66, in num_classes
    return super().num_classes
  File "/home/shaozhulin/.conda/envs/szlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/dataset.py", line 159, in num_classes
    data_list = _get_flattened_data_list([data for data in self])
  File "/home/shaozhulin/.conda/envs/szlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/dataset.py", line 159, in <listcomp>
    data_list = _get_flattened_data_list([data for data in self])
  File "/home/shaozhulin/.conda/envs/szlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/dataset.py", line 259, in __getitem__
    data = data if self.transform is None else self.transform(data)
  File "/home/ai/data/szl/GNN-FakeNews-main/gnn_model/data_loader.py", line 89, in __call__
    edge_index = to_undirected(data.edge_index, data.x.size(0))
  File "/home/shaozhulin/.conda/envs/szlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/utils/undirected.py", line 173, in to_undirected
    return coalesce(edge_index, edge_attr, num_nodes, reduce)
  File "/home/shaozhulin/.conda/envs/szlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/utils/coalesce.py", line 99, in coalesce
    idx[1:].mul_(num_nodes).add_(edge_index[int(sort_by_row)])
TypeError: mul_(): argument 'other' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str
```

How can I solve this problem? Is there an error in data processing?

Comment: Is `edge_index` the correct data type?